# Initial loading of Data from Storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need help.

I've developed an App which works fine if u use it already or started the app the second time. 
But there is a problem for the new Users.

I Used Ionic4 with Angular. 
If the App starts the app.component write some data in the local storage and try to get them but I think the Lifecycle is the Problem here.

So Use Case:

A New User Download my Application and see a White Screen with the Tab bar. 
If he switches the View and Switchback he sees the correct View with the Data from the App Storage.

If he now starts the App again the App works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to display the app.component only when the local storage is loaded

Comment: Do you now how?

Comment: use a boolean on app.component.html and when the service you have to load the local storage is complete change that boolean to true